# MS Teams invite guest using graph api

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to invite a guest (external user) to my Microsoft Teams team using graph api. I'm doing the following:

1. Create the invite using create invite api available in Microsoft graph
2. Add the guest to the team upon success

On the guest side, they receive an invitation email which guides them through the account creation process. Post microsoft account creation, they are asked to create a Teams account (most of our guests do not have a Teams account as well). During this process, they are being asked for Teams organization name which takes them to a completely different Teams org than the one that they were invited for.

Is there anything wrong in what I'm doing?

Comment: For Teams account creation any mail id can be used (you don't need to have Teams account for it).  About organization name - we can [select organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MLqF.png) from top right corner of the Teams screen.

Comment: I too am trying to set this up so that I hook a Microsoft Form to a Flow that created the Guest account in teams. I can do it in PowerShell with no issues, but I am now trying to automate the process...